# Duplicates are being imported into Exchange Mailboxes

Tags: exchange, outlook, microsoft-office, exchange-2016

I am using the `New-MailboxImportRequest` to import .PST files into existing mailboxes. These mailboxes have emails in them that are also included in the .PST file being imported.

The import request completes successfully, some needing the `BadItemLimit` to be set. After importing the .PST file, I am noticing that duplicates have been created for emails and contacts.

From this [site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-mailboximportrequest?view=exchange-ps),  I understand that duplicates are not imported.

This was due to a corrupt Exchange database.

A new empty database was created to allow email access and flow. Some users had cached Exchange mode enabled before the database corruption.

These locally cached emails were exported to .pst using Outlook and then imported into the empty Exchange database and respective mailbox. Most users did not have "All" cached. Data was later recovered from a backup before the corruption exporting each mailbox to a .pst file, these recovered .pst files were then imported into each user new mailbox.

This is an example of the PowerShell command used:

```perl
New-MailboxImportRequest -FilePath "\\ServerName\FolderLocation\UserName.pst" -BadItemLimit 10 -Mailbox "UserName"
```

This is an on premise Exchange 2016 server.

So, to my questions,

- How do I stop the duplicates from being imported?
- How do I remove the duplicates for those already imported?

Comment: Hi, is there any update?

Answer (score -1):

I found a similar thread: **[Duplicates are being imported](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2323715-duplicates-are-being-imported?page=1#entry-9215028)**, please check if the answers in it are helpful to you.

Comment: I am testing today using the -ConflictResolutionOption parameter

The Conversation Clean Up process has been used in the past and did not remove the duplicates.

Comment: If there is any update, please let us know.